# Prototype Bean Destruction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, garbage-collection

I have the below PROTOTYPE class .

1, Will my `DemoService` objects destroyed by spring?And will it be garbage collected?
2. How can i manually destroy the `DemoService` so it is Garbage Collected?

```
@Service
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public class DemoService {


@Autowired
private DaoCall daoCall;  //call to database.Connection will be closed by the connection pool.

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template; //used to send message to Kafka
}
```

I am injecting DemoService prototype class in the singleton class GreetingController

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

@Autowired
private DemoService demoService;

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting()
    
    {
    
    demoService. //call to demoService
    
    return  "Hello ";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a prototype bean this way it's only going to be created once when the singleton bean is created and it will only be destroyed when the spring context is shutdown.

You need to get a reference to it using the `ApplicationContext`

```
public class GreetingController implements ApplicationContextAware {
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
      throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting()
    
    {
  
    DemoService demoService = applicationContext.getBean(DemoService.class);
    demoService. //call to demoService

    return  "Hello ";
    }
}
```

Then it will be garbage collected when you stop using it as any other java object.

Many more ways to get and instance of a prototype bean see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton

Comment: so i have 3 doubts
1)the way i have used in my sample is the correct way to inject Prototype bean into Singleton bean .Or your way?
2)Will there be any memory leak due to my DemoService  prototype scope .From your answer i guess no
3)`If you use a prototype bean this way it's only going to be created once when the singleton bean is created `.Why do you say this ?Can you please explain a bit

Comment: 1) Your way is not correct. The way I showed here and other ways you can see in the linked page are correct. 2) Only if you create it, it will behave exactly as any other java object. 3) Spring creates the singleton bean and inject the prototype bean into it, this happens only once.